# where is Buffer.forEach specified?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that I can [iterate over a Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_iteration) with:

```
for( const b of buffer ){
  console.log(b);
}
```

But I noticed I can also call .forEach, .map, etc.

```
$ node
> const buffer = new Buffer.from([1,2,3]);
undefined
> buffer.forEach( b => console.log( b ) );
1
2
3
undefined
> buffer.map( b => 'value:' + b.toString() ).toString();
'\x00\x00\x00'
```

Apparently these methods are not specified on the [node.js Buffer page](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer), and also I don't understand why it behaves as it does (e.g. '\x00\x00\x00').

Where are the methods .forEach, .map, etc. on the Buffer type specified ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right from the Nodejs [Buffer doc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarrays).

> Buffer instances are also JavaScript Uint8Array and TypedArray
> instances. All TypedArray methods are available on Buffers.

And, you can see [all sorts of methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) on a `TypedArray` including the ones you mention in your question.

If you go look at the [implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/buffer.js#L954) of the nodejs Buffer object, you will see that it is made from something they refer to as a `FastBuffer`.  That inherits a bunch of things from `Uint8Array` which is likely  where the methods you asked about come from:

```
class FastBuffer extends Uint8Array
```

And, there is also a function used to populate the prototype with all sorts of additional methods [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/buffer.js#L963).

---

And, for a little diagnostics, if you run this code in nodejs:

```
let b = Buffer.alloc(100);

console.log(`Buffer instanceof Buffer: ${b instanceof Buffer}`);
console.log(`Buffer instanceof Uint8Array: ${b instanceof Uint8Array}`);
```

you will see this output:

```
Buffer instanceof Buffer: true
Buffer instanceof Uint8Array: true
```

---

And, then if you walk the prototype chain with this:

```
let proto = Buffer.prototype;
while (proto) {
    console.log(proto.constructor.name);
    proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
}
```

You will get this output that shows the class inheritance:

```
Buffer
Uint8Array
TypedArray
Object
```

Comment: Added inheritance diagnostics to show the full class hierarchy with code.